# Trouble trying to override -= operator

Tags: c++

So I have two objects, which contain a vector of file objects called files (which may either contain a file or a directory file as well as all files it points to). If I do something like B2 -= B1, I want it to remove everything everything in B1 from B2 if applicable. I compare if the file objects are the same by checking their ino_t inode and their dev_t devicenumber.

Currently this is my code

```
Someclass& Someclass::operator-=(const Someclass &rhs){
    vector<AnotherClass> retfiles;
        for (auto i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(files.size()); i++){
            for (auto j = 0; j < static_cast<int (rhs.files.size()); j++){

            if (i < j){
                if (!isSameFile(files.at(i), rhs.files.at(i))){
                    retfiles.push_back(files.at(i));
                    }
            }
        }

    files = retfiles; 

    return *this;
}

bool Someclass::isSameFile(const AnotherClass &lhs, const AnotherClass &rhs) { 
    return (lhs.getInode() == rhs.getInode()) && (lhs.getDeviceNumber() == rhs.getDeviceNumber());
}
```

My issue is that I'm not able to successfully remove the files from the lefthand side correctly (in the case that the rhs object may contain more files than the lhs object) or in the case of removing duplicates from my vector.

```
SomeClass 1:
-rw-r--r-- pub/tree/alpha/iota/omega
-r--r--r-- pub/tree/alpha/iota/kappa
drwxr-xr-x pub/tree/alpha/iota
```

```
SomeClass 2:
-rw-r--r-- pub/tree2/tau/sigma
drwxr-xr-x pub/tree2/tau
-rw-r--r-- /etc/group
```

```
SomeClass 3:
```

When `SomeClass3-=SomeClass2` should look like

```
-rw-r--r-- pub/tree/alpha/iota/omega
-r--r--r-- pub/tree/alpha/iota/kappa
drwxr-xr-x pub/tree/alpha/iota
```

Comment: the innermost if and else bodies are identical, could that be a source of your problems?

Comment: As mentioned your it has no effect, also you’re adding multiples since at every comparison you add if that one doesn’t match. Rather go through the whole list and see if there’s a match and only then determine what to do

Comment: I guess I'd say that I'm a bit lost with this, so by removing that else on the inner loop now I just don't have anything being added to the Vector<AnotherClass> retfile.

Comment: Why do you check `if (i < j)`?  Other than that you never use `j` inside your loop.

Comment: In the case that the rhs vector contains more files than the lhs argument, so I don't go out of bounds.

Comment: @Thegreatfoo You should index with `i` in `files`, and with `j` in `rhs.files`, and add an item from `files` only if it’s different from all of `rhs.files`.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the elements from an array that don't exist in another array is called the *set difference* and there is a function in the standard library that can do that.

```
vector<AnotherClass> retfiles;
std::set_difference(files.begin(), files.end(),
                    rhs.files.begin(), rhs.files.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(retfiles), isSameFile);
// retfiles contains elements from files that didn't exists in rhs.files
```

You'll need `#include <algorithm>` for [set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) and `#include <iterator>` for [back_inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Edit:

Actually `isSameFile` doesn't do quite what set_difference needs it to do. You'll need to use a comparison function to sort the arrays and use that same function for the set_difference.

In your comment below, `cmp` would do that fine if `getDeviceNumber` is the only thing that distinguished the files, but I see you have `getInode` as well. So you might want to make a comparison function like this:

```
bool cmp(const Fing &lhs, const Fing &rhs) { // typo?
    if (lhs.getDeviceNumber() != rhs.getDeviceNumber())
        return lhs.getDeviceNumber() < rhs.getDeviceNumber();
    else
        return lhs.getInode() < rhs.getInode();
}
```

and use that to sort with and pass to set_difference.

Comment: Thank you! Would this still work in the case that I try to do this on the same object? Such as SomeClass a1 -= SomeClass a2? In that case it would return an empty array?

Comment: Doesn't `std::set_difference` require the inputs to be sorted?

Comment: @Thegreatfoo yes, `retfiles` would be empty if `files` and `rhs.files` are identical

Comment: @kmdreko I have a method `bool cmp(const Fing &lhs, const Fing &rhs){
 return lhs.getDeviceNumber() < rhs.getDeviceNumber();
} ` Would I be able to incorporate this in order to sort the files before using set_difference?

Comment: @Thegreatfoo undefined reference errors? that's weird... that'd happen if your program isn't being built properly or if a function is used but not defined...

Comment: @kmdreko I forgot to include the class name when I was using the compare function. Small mistake on my behalf. Though I am running into one issue though, it seems that even when I do something like SomeClass1 -= SomeClass1 I have 1 AnotherClass left in the vector. Could this possibly be due to something with the Inode/Device numbers?

Comment: @Thegreatfoo I cannot think of a way that the set_difference would yield any values with the same arrays unless they weren't sorted the same way as the comparison function or if the device/inode was being modified